# Using Entity Framework Data Annotations to Achieve One to Many Relationship With Eager Loading

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations, one-to-many, eager-loading

I've seen plenty of examples not using Data Annotations and can get a one-to-one relationship working, but having difficulty with a one-to-many.

We have parts that we will randomly take sample weights on to make sure our machine house is producing to spec. The one-to-one relationship for Material will load. Having trouble with the QualityMeasurements one-to-many.

Anyone have experience with this?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Part {

    [Key]
    public string PartID { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MaterialID")]
    public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
    public int MaterialID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PartNumber")]
    public virtual ICollection<QualityMeasurement> Qualities { get; set; }
}

public class Material {

    [Key]
    public int MaterialID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double Density { get; set; }

}

public class QualityMeasurement  {

    public int QualityID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public double UnitWeight { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having troubles because in the `one-to-many` relationship, the `foreign key` should be defined at the `many` side and should relate to the `primary key` of the `one` side.

Your model should be something like this:

```
public class Part {

    [Key]
    public string PartID { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MaterialID")]
    public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
    public int MaterialID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QualityMeasurement> Qualities { get; set; }
}

public class QualityMeasurement  {

    [Key]
    public int QualityID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PartID")]
    public virtual Part Part { get; set; }
    public string PartID { get; set; }

    public double UnitWeight { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very clear description of the way the relationship needs to be setup.

Comment: I removed the comments, it was an unrelated error on my part. Thanks again

Comment: Can you address the 'eager loading' part of the question?

Comment: @MecaMatt Not sure what do you mean. Once you have a proper model, eager loading it is like any other. I mean, nothing special, using `Include` / `ThenInclude`  etc.